# How to setup a "watch" for notifications in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I would like to setup a simple notifications system for my web app that is written in Ruby on Rails. My website is a simple auction site, but each auction has 2 stages: a 5 day "no minimum bid" stage where anyone can bid and a 3 day "$1 minimum bid" stage where only the top 10% of the bidders from the previous stage can bid.

I want to notify my users when the auction goes from the first stage to the second. What is the best way to do this?

I've thought of two design options:

- I don't know RoR has this, and whether this is an efficient system (because I want to build a system that will have thousands of users participating in hundreds of auctions - whether it gets that big or not is irrelevant, this is sort of a side project for me to learn to write high quality, scalable RoR) but basically, when a user bids on an auction, they become an observer of some sort on the auction. Then, somehow at the 5 day mark, all the listeners are notified. I don't know how that trigger happens though in RoR (is there some way to say "trigger after 5 days from creation" or some such thing?). To summarize, I would like to use the Observer pattern.

  The key issue for me is trying to figure out how to trigger after a set period of time. The best way to do it, I think, would be for each auction to have some set state variable called "auction state". After a certain period of time, that would transition, and at that point every observer on the auction would get notified.
- There is a rake task that runs everyday at some set time each day. It goes through each auction and if any auction is on day 6, the observers of that auction are notified. This seems like a pretty bad way of going about it - I like the idea of having a state-ful auction.

Thoughts?

Thanks!
Ringo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler, if you haven't heard yet, resque is a gem for creating background processing, having queues in redis. This gem resque-scheduler, lets you specify when to run a task/job.

For example in your model you would have an after_create to schedule the task for changing the bid state.

```
  after_create :shedule_state_change

  private
    def record_signup
      Resque.enqueue_in(5.days, ChangeState)
    end
```

And then you could notify all the bidders for that bid inside that task or create an observer for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine, specifically transitions callbacks. Alternatively you can also use the standard active record callbacks http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html